# How can I access the 'type' attribute from the 'students' array in the API response using Flutter, Laravel, and PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, api

```
"data": {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "tala",
    "role": "Student",
    "email": "tala@gmail.com",
    "students": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "tala",
            "type": "Master_Degree",
            "year": "third",
            "Semester": null,
            "specializations": "جراحة",
            

        }
    ]
},
```

I used to get email by doing this:
`response['data']['email']`

how could I get the 'type' from `response['data']['student']` ??

Comment: `response['data']['students'][0]['type']`?

Comment: Hi Anna. I guess your question is lacking quite some details making it difficult to help. Maybe edit your question and provide more background.

Answer (score 0):

in your `data` object , students are an array of objects !

so many students can be added to it !

to access to a student attribute you have to loop into the students array .

```
$students = response["data"]["students"];

foreach($students as $student ) {
  //access to each student in your list
  // do what ever you want
}
```